# How do I make the buttons' animation animated?

Tags: css

I am creating my portfolio page which I am currently animating the buttons' animation and my background is a simple particle animation as my background which powered by javascript. I noticed that the canvas which is the simple particle animation in the css file which I have set my canvas position to other elements except for absolute which is preventing the buttons animation from animating.

I tried changing the position to other elements and it's works for the buttons animation but when I changed the canvas position to absolute , the buttons' animation stopped working again

Here's my code ( html code )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <title>Welcome to my Page!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abril+Fatface&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Righteous&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Jhan's Page</h1>
                <div class="buttons">
                <a href="#" class="button"><span>Button1</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="button"><span>Button2</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="button"><span>Button3</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="button"><span>Button4</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <canvas id="waveCanvas"></canvas>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

( css code )

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

canvas {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

h1 {
    color: #f5d442;
    font-family: 'Righteous', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 800px; /* Creates space between heading and buttons */
}

.buttons {
    margin-left: 400px; /* Adjust the margin for the desired space */
}

.button{
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-right: 60px; /* Adjust as needed for button spacing */
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: #363636;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.button:span{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.button::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2196f3;
    transition: width 0.5s,height 0.5s;
}

.button:hover::before{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

javascript file

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('waveCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let particlesArray;

// Define particle properties
class Particle {
  constructor() {
    this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
    this.size = Math.random() * 3 + 1;
    this.speedX = Math.random() * 3 - 1.5;
    this.speedY = Math.random() * 3 - 1.5;
  }

  update() {
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY;

    if (this.size > 0.2) this.size -= 0.1;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

function init() {
  particlesArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    particlesArray.push(new Particle());
  }
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (let i = 0; i < particlesArray.length; i++) {
    particlesArray[i].update();
    particlesArray[i].draw();
    // Reset particles when they go off-screen
    if (particlesArray[i].x < 0 || particlesArray[i].x > canvas.width || particlesArray[i].y < 0 || particlesArray[i].y > canvas.height) {
      particlesArray[i] = new Particle();
    }
  }
}

init();
animate();

// Update canvas size when the window is resized
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  init();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canvas being on top of everything, prevents the buttons from being hovered with the cursor.

Just add `pointer-events: none;` for your `canvas` element, so that it "ignores" the mouse cursor.

Comment: @jhan please do not use comments to state that something works. According to the So guidelines "thank you" comments are off-topic. If you find an answer helpful, upvote it. If an answer is solving your question you can also checkmark it as an correct answer.